# office 365 email privacy after having left job

Tags: office365, privacy

I was terminated from my current job few days ago. I am a EU citizen, Finnish to be precise.
Could some one tell me if there is something I can do or Microsoft office 365 does to keep my mailbox at my ex job private?

Can my employer reset my password (I have not given permission) and make copies of my mail or read my mails. Is there something on Microsoft side in place to prevent this kind of abuse of privacy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to programming, is very vague, and is likely to result in opinions rather than facts.

Answer (score 0):

If the Office365 account was provided by your employer, it's theirs, not yours, and you have no particular rights over email communications conducted as part of your employment. Why would you expect to continue to be able to use an account they are paying for after you've stopped working for them? If you were using their account for your personal communications, that was a poor choice by you, and probably prohibited by your employment contract anyway. Their GDPR basis for processing will be contract or statutory requirement (not consent), and there will be a ton of case law on this kind of thing.

If you were using a personal account for business, they will have no rights to that, no ability to reset your password, nor access your email, however, you may have broken your contract if you used it for work-related email, for which they may have recourse.

There is no abuse of privacy here. If you want further advice, ask a lawyer, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did not use my official mailing address for personal stuffs. I used only work email for work related stuff, but still I  dont like the idea that they can reset my password and read all my mails, sent received etc.

Comment: If it's work related, it's theirs to do what they like with. Are you expecting them to pretend you never existed? Is whoever took over your job expected to start from scratch on every client conversation and project, rather than referring to your earlier conversations?

Comment: i want all the companies to understand the mailbox they provide to their employee belong to them but the mails inside them do not belong to them. It is private to the employee.

Comment: Good luck with that. It's their data, not yours. The people you were communicating with were *their* clients, not yours. The work you were doing was for them, not you.